# Add unit symbol at the end of the EditText

Tags: android

I have one EditText witch is of type numberDecimal. I would like to have the unit symbol (for instance m, km, kg, g) at the end of the value. I have found many posts here at stackoverflow that tells to use TextWatcher or InputFilter, but what I would really love to is to restrict this unit symbol to not being editable for the user.

So when you edit the value in the textbox, you can't move the courser to manipulate/delete the symbol. It is basically not a editable part of the value.

I'm sure this is possible to achieve, but Im not sure how much custom code I need to write to make it work. Are there any SDK support for this?

Ismar

Comment: Put a `TextView` at the end of the `EditText` and have it display the units.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dip" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/browseurl"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:textColor="#BCBCBC"
                    android:textSize="14dip"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/cross"
                    android:layout_width="25dip"
                    android:layout_height="25dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="false" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Replace the ImageButton with either a textbox or a image button for units.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints. Here is my solution, I have one linearlayout with 20dip margin to the  left and right. Inside of the layout I have one EditText and one TextViw. I set weight to 1 on the EditText so it fills any remaining space in the parent view.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value_unit_symbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:text="kg"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```