# How to put units in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to put the `unit text (like lbs, kg etc..)` in `Edittext`

When I looked for here simply, they suggested using a text view or an image as a solution.

([Add unit symbol at the end of the EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026932/add-unit-symbol-at-the-end-of-the-edittext))

Is there any way to use only EditText?

I want to put the unit text which is fixed inside the `EditText`.

This unit does not disappear even when i input it, but the unit can be changed by a `popup menu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [This](https://github.com/tobiasschuerg/android-prefix-suffix-edit-text) library to show both suffix and prefix to an EditText like the following:

```
<com.tobiasschuerg.prefixsuffix.PrefixSuffixEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="numberDecimal"
      android:text="24"
      app:prefix="Age: "
      app:suffix=" years"
      android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using Java. Does this matter for both Kotlin and Java?

Comment: Yeah it does not matter if it is java or kotlin.